# Matlab 2016b: looping with structures is much slower than with variables

Tags: matlab, profiling

I am computing a list of error statistics of a variable u. Whenever I put the structures in the loop, Matlab becomes superslow, while it is pretty fast with standard variables. I have heard that with Matlab 2016b one can either use loops or use vectorized notation, the speed should be the same. It looks like it does not work for structures. Do you know why? Best suggestion here? This is a minimal example ( I just used trivial "if" clauses, mine are more complex and that's the main reason why I don't vectorize):

```
    n = 1000,
    m = 1000;
    uMODEL = rand(n,m);
    uOBS = rand(n,m);
    %
    %
    %
    tic
    ERRORS = struct('Emedio',0,'MAE',0,'sigma',0,'Emax',0,'Emin',0);
    Nerr(1:max(n,1),1) = 0; %Nerr at most it contains n
    fields = fieldnames(ERRORS);
    for i = 1:numel(fields)
        ERRORS.(fields{i}) = zeros(max(n,1),1);
    end

    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n
        if (1000>2 && 2000<343532)
            diff  = uMODEL(j,i)-uOBS(j,i);
            ERRORS.Emedio(j) = ERRORS.Emedio(j) + diff;
            ERRORS.MAE(j)    = ERRORS.MAE(j)     + abs(diff);
            ERRORS.sigma(j)  = ERRORS.sigma(j)  + diff^2;
            ERRORS.Emax(j)  = max(ERRORS.Emax(j),diff);
            ERRORS.Emin(j) = min(ERRORS.Emin(j),diff);
            Nerr(n)    = Nerr(n) + 1;
        end
        end
    end
    ERRORS.Emedio(:) = ERRORS.Emedio(:)./Nerr(:);
    ERRORS.MAE(:)    = ERRORS.MAE(:)./Nerr(:);
    ERRORS.sigma(:)  = sqrt(ERRORS.sigma(:)./(Nerr(:)-1));


    toc
    clear  ERRORS
    tic
    %
    % here instead I define variables, I fill them up and then I throw them in structures, cause loops with structures are strangely slow...
    Emedio = zeros(max(n,1),1);
    MAE = zeros(max(n,1),1);
    sigma = zeros(max(n,1),1);
    Nerr = zeros(max(n,1),1);
    Emax = zeros(max(n,1),1);
    Emin = zeros(max(n,1),1);

    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n
        if (1000>2 && 2000<343532)
            diff  = uMODEL(j,i)-uOBS(j,i);
            Emedio(j) = Emedio(j) + diff;
            MAE(j)    = MAE(j)     + abs(diff);
            sigma(j)  = sigma(j)  + diff^2;
            Emax(j)  = max(Emax(j),diff);
            Emin(j) = min(Emin(j),diff);
            Nerr(n)    = Nerr(n) + 1;
        end
        end
    end
    Emedio(:) = Emedio(:)./Nerr(:);
    MAE(:)    = MAE(:)./Nerr(:);
    sigma(:)  = sqrt(sigma(:)./(Nerr(:)-1));

    ERRORS.Emedio(:) = Emedio(:);
    ERRORS.MAE(:)    = MAE(:);
    ERRORS.sigma(:)  = sigma(:);
    ERRORS.Emax(:)   = Emax(:);
    ERRORS.Emin(:)   = Emin(:);
    toc
```

the output is:

```
  Elapsed time is 2.372765 seconds.
  Elapsed time is 0.057719 seconds.
```

Comment: the JIT compiler gets triggered with specific code. If the JIT compiler does not udnerstand how to optimise your code (e.g. because it has structures) it will just not "auto-vectorize" your code and thus  there wont be speedup. I guess this is what is happening

Comment: Accessing the struct in iteration could also explain the issue.